# Hightlight certain days in TMonthCalendar component

Tags: c++builder, highlight, vcl, monthcalendar

I am working with a TMonthCalendar VCL component in C++Builder and I am wanting to highlight certain days in a month changing its color font or its forecolor.

I have seen this properties exists in the component but the changes are applied to all days and I need to apply only to a few days. In the other hand, I tried using bolddays function but days are not highlighted enough...

How to highlight specific days in this component?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but the standard OS MonthCalendar control that `TMonthCalendar` wraps simply does not support custom fonts or colors.  Using the `OnGetMonthInfo` and `OnGetMonthBoldInfo` events, and the `BoldDays()` method, all you can do is specify whether individual days are displayed as bold or not.  If that does not suit your need, then you will have to create your own custom MonthCalendar control from scratch, or find a third-party implementation.